# java org.json not supporting special characters like \uf4f8 ,\uf389\uf60d \u2026 emojis)

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, org.json

I have java string like below and I am trying to convert to JSONArray using org.json library.

```
 String content = "[{  \"message\":\"This year\\u2019s #SexiestManAlive goes to @chrisevans \\uf389\\uf60d \\u2026they did this one for us \\uf979\\n(\\uf4f8: @mschwartzphoto x @people )\"}]"
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(content);
```

When I am converting this to JSONArray some extends emojis are not converting  (\uf4f8 ,\uf389\uf60d \u2026". )

***it looks like this after converting this msg to jsonarray***

"This year’s #SexiestManAlive goes to @chrisevans  …they did this one for us 凉\n(: @mschwartzphoto x @people )"

How can we handle this  ? please need help on this.

***For Reference:: actually text message in API looks like this***
This year’s #SexiestManAlive goes to @chrisevans  …they did this one for us 
(: @mschwartzphoto x @people )

Comment: U+F389  is defined in the private use area and **not** an emoji. The part popper emoji however is U+1F389. The suspicious similarity of this value leads me to believe that whatever produced your string doesn't correctly handle characters outside of the BMP (i.e. Unicode codepoints greater than 0xFFFF) and cut off data. If you want proper emoji support you **must** make sure that all parts handling strings have complete unicode support (or at the very least don't mangle data that passes through).

Comment: will support  Java related json ibrary all emoji's (U+1F43F ....)?

Comment: Since escaped Non-BMP codepoints are actually encoded in UTF-16 in JSON, this maps *directly* onto how Java represents them in String, so even if a Json library was not written with this in mind, it will *very likely* just do the right thing. I've personally not yet seen a Java JSON library that chokes on those. But again: your input string does **not** correctly encode those emojis.

Comment: @JoachimSauer,  through java and post man also its coming like this 

" \uf389\uf60d \u2026they did this one for us \uf979\n(\uf4f8:"

Comment: Yes, that means that whatever produces that JSON is already messing things up. There's no reliable way to fix it after the fact, the producing side needs to be fixed.